# Swashbuckle Swagger UI does not show parameters description

Tags: asp.net, swagger, swashbuckle

Package version 6.0.0-beta902

Examples :

```
public class TestModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is description of Name
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public IActionResult HelloWorld(TestModel model)
{
    return Content("hello " + model.Name);
}
```

Why Swagger UI does not show Name parameter description ?

Answer (score 4):

This is commonly caused by a missing configuration, make sure you have the IncludeXmlComments with the correct path to your XML document.

Here is a way to include all XML documents on the configuration:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add Swashbuckle
        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
            options.SingleApiVersion(new Swashbuckle.Swagger.Model.Info()
            {
                Title = "My API",
                Version = "v1",
                Description = "My API",
                TermsOfService = "Terms Of Service"
            });

            //Set the comments path for the swagger json and ui.
            var basePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
            foreach (var name in Directory.GetFiles(basePath, "*.XML", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                options.IncludeXmlComments(name);
            }
        });
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

Here is an example showing correctly:

http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=TestEnum#/TestEnum/TestEnum_Put

And the code behind that is on GitHub:

https://github.com/heldersepu/SwashbuckleTest/blob/master/Swagger_Test/Models/ViewModelTest.cs

Comment: I verify, all my xml files are well included. Swagger show the remarks from my models property. But there is nothing in the parameter description .

Comment: Can you add your project to GitHub and post a link here?

Comment: I just tried with that exact same version and it works fine for me:
https://github.com/heldersepu/csharp-proj/commit/d5043caadf787d409dfa7b00165454c5e3823f3b

Comment: Thank you for your help ! What is your version of Swashbuckle ?

Comment: I've tried with multiple versions 6.0.0-beta901, 6.0.0-beta902 they all work fine.  Can you add your project to GitHub and post a link here?